# Order in which threads leave wait queue

Tags: java, multithreading

If I use synchronised methods or locks and some threads enter wait queue, do they leave the wait queue in same order as they entered it? In other words, does the first thread to enter wait queue also leave it first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802830/ensure-java-synchonized-locks-are-taken-in-order

Answer (score 0):

No, the `JVM` chooses randomly a `Thread` to wake from waiting state either one uses `notify()` or `notifyAll()` to wake them. In particular with `notify()` only one Thread will randomly be chosen to enter the excecution state, while with `notifyAll()` all the waiting `Threads` together, but there is no guarantee in what order will they be excecuted.

Comment: but is there a way to achieve the behaviour I mentioned with syncronized method?

Comment: @Rohit: you'd have to use a ReentrantLock. see the question that this is being voted a duplicate of.

Comment: I checked that one, but I'd like to know is ReentrantLock the only way to ensure that kind of behaviour?

Comment: btw the wording on this answer is not good, Stephen C's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1802862/217324 applies.