# busy spin to reduce context switch latency (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, queue

In my application there are several services that process information on their own thread, when they are done they post a message to the next service which then continue to do its work on its own thread. The handover of messages is done via a LinkedBlockingQueue. The handover normally takes 50-80 us (from putting a message on the queue until the consumer starts to process the message). 
To speed up the handover on the most important services I wanted to use a busy spin instead of a blocking approach (I have 12 processor cores and want to dedicate 3 to these important services).
So.. I changed LinkedBlockingQueue to ConcurrentLinkedQueue

and did

```
for(;;)
{
 Message m = queue.poll();
 if( m != null )
  ....
}
```

Now.. the result is that the first message pass takes 1 us, but then the latency increases over the next 25 handovers until reaches 500 us and then the latency is suddenly back to 1 us and the starts to increase.. So I have latency cycles with 25 iterations where latency starts at 1 us and ends at 500 us. (message are passed approximately 100 times per second)

with an average latency of 250 it is not exactly the performance gain I was looking for.

I also tried to use the LMAX Disruptor ringbuffer instead of the ConcurrentLinkedQueue. That framwork have its own build in busy spin implementation and a quite different queue implementation, but the result was the same. So im quite certain that its not the fault of the queue or me abusing something..

Question is.. What the Heck is going on here? Why am I seeing this strange latency cycles?

Cheers!!

Comment: Do you track the number of spin cycles that drew blanks? Maybe the latency is with the thread scheduler. How do you ensure the thread has 100% ownership of a core?

Comment: This sounds scheduler related. What OS are you running this on?

Comment: 'message are passed approximately 100 times per second' - that's 10ms, right?  So, with the blocking queues, 50-80us is added on to 10ms.  Is it that important to reduce that added latency?  Even if it is, spinning on a queue pop, (as distinct from a spinlock used to protect the queue for the brief period while objects are pushed/popped), is a CPU/memory-bandwidth black hole - hopeless.

Comment: #Marko, Angler. Yes, I am also suspecting the OS scheduler, I am runnig windows and java so there is no way of assigning a core to a process. The only thing i can do is to not run more threads than I have cores.

Comment: #Martin, Messages are posted with 10ms intervals, but for one Event to be created processed and reach its destination takes approx. 500 us. which involves 3 context switches of above mentioned sort. so up to half of the latency consists of just switching threads.. Yes, maby its hopeless.. :)

Comment: Busy-waiting on an inter-thread queue is bad for CPU and memory-badwidth, but gets much worse if there are more ready threads than cores.  In that case, the OS has no idea that the busy-waiting threads are doing no useful work and is quite happy to run them all while a producer thread that could issue some work objects is held ready, unable to get a core until it gets scheduled again due to the timer interrupt :((

Comment: The interaction of caches, cache coherence protocols, scheduler, etc. is intractable in a case like this I feel. Even if you did get it to work, one Windows update or JVM patch could throw the whole thing off. I know this isn't the answer to your question, but it may be a nearly-unanswerable question so: the whole approach just seems wrong. Anyway, if you want to figure it out, I would say you should monitor the queue depth and execution duration. How long does it take to process one item before it tries to get the next? How deep does the queue get? How many times does it draw blank? ...more:

Comment: ...cont'd: System.nanoTime() may not be 100% accurate or consistent across cores. Anyway if you poll() a null often it means the queue is usually empty, so using multithreading is just overhead; do it on one thread and get 0 latency. Other idea: Haven't checked the implementation of poll but maybe try some other signaling mechanism. Try AtomicBoolean. In the producer use .set(true). In the consumer, poll() only if .getAndSet(false) returns true. But be VERY careful to avoid a race condition--make sure the queue is empty before the next call to getAndSet--it may have more than 1 item waiting.

Comment: Why are you passing the message from thread to thread instead of having a single thread work on it to completion? Clearly you don't need high processing volume, so why pick a design that makes latency worse, when that's the thing you care most about?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know thread scheduler can deliberately pause a thread for a longer time if it detects that this thread is using CPU quite intensively - to distribute CPU time between different threads fairer. Try adding `LockSupport.park()` in the consumer after queue is empty  and `LockSupport.unpark()` in the producer after adding the message - it might make the latency less variable; whether it will actually be better comparing to blocking queue is a big question though.

Comment: The jitter-ed pattern disappeared but it actually increased latency (double compared to blockingQueue).

Comment: The scheduler has no way of determining that a running thread is not actually doing any useful work and so, for example, would be quite happy to run [cores] polling threads and so deny CPU to producer/s that could otherwise issue more useful work.  As well as soaking up CPU cores and heating up the room, polling queues loads up the interprocessor memory paths with huge piles of gunge atomic ops. Horrible..

Comment: @Martin - obviously scheduler has no way of figuring out what a thread is doing, but it can track the time it actually doing something (being in the runnning state); my point was that the thread which spend much more time in the running state than others can get a shorter timeslice at some point, or be purposely delayed. I do agree that spining is generally a bad idea.

Comment: OK, so if non-blocking queue does not improve performance try to attack that problem from a different angle. How about doing more stuff in each thread - 1 larger thread pool doing 3 steps at once instead of 3 smaller each doing 1 step? You mentioned overall latency about 500 micros, that suggests you do primarily computations and logging (no remote calls, SQL etc) - extensive multithreadig in this case is not your friend.

Comment: There is actually a lot more to it that motivates the threading model being the way it is. Changing the architecture is possibly, but the topic of this post should be focused on how to reduce context switch latency, not only as a solution to the problem at hand but in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need doing the job the way you described (and not the way Andrey Nudko replied at Jan 5 at 13:22), then you definitedly need looking at the problem also from other viewpoints.

Just some hints:

1. Try checking your overall environment (outside the JVM). For example:

   - OS CPU scheduler has a huge impact on this..currently the default is very likely 
     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler
   - number of running processes, etc.
2. "problems" inside your JVM

   - garbage collector (try different one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Types%20of%20Collectors%7Coutline)
3. Try changing thread priorities: [Setting priority to Java's threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617963/setting-priority-to-javas-threads)

Answer (score 0):

This is just wild speculation (since as others have mentioned, you're not gathering any information on the queue length, failed polls, null polls etc.):

I used the force and read the [source of ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue-source.html), or rather, briefly leafed through it for a minute or two. The polling is not quite your trivial O(1) operation. It might be the case that you're traversing more than a few nodes which have become stale, holding null; and there might be additional transitory states involving nodes linking to themselves as the next node as indication of staleness/removal from the queue. It may be that the queue is starting to build up garbage due to thread scheduling. Try following the links to the abstract algorithm mentioned in the code:

[**Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue**](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/michael/PODC96.html) by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott (link has a PDF and pseudocode).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents. If you are running on linux/unix based systems, there is a way to dedicate a certain cpu to a certain thread. In essence, you can make the OS ignore that cpu for any scheduling. Checkout the isolation levels for cpu